# In what situation, the file has nothing when capture picture use MediaStore.Extra_Output

Tags: android, image, file, camera, mediastore

Below is how I capture an image

```
Intent getImageByCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
MyConst.file = new File(Util.Second_PATH,System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");                          getImageByCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(MyConst.file));
startActivityForResult(getImageByCamera);
```

My file path is like below:

```
Util.Second_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator
            + "baletu"
            + File.separator
            + "images/";
```

I cannot get the image file on some devices.

In what situation could this happen so I can work out a fix?

Answer (score 0):

> below is how i capture image

You are not using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`. Hence, your picture should be a thumbnail, obtained from `getData().getExtra("data")` on the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()` for your `startActivityForResult()` call.

> And my file path is like below:

Do not use string concatenation to create file paths. Use the proper `File` constructor, which can handle cases where `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` either does or does not have a trailing directory separator.

Also note that if you do start using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, [a `file:` `Uri` may not work on the next version of Android](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html).

> in what situation could this happen

Camera apps have bugs. There are over 8,000 Android device models. There are hundreds of built-in camera apps spanning those models, and there are other camera apps available for download. Some have buggy implementations of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Delegating image capture to a third-party app is unreliable. Either live with that fact (and fail gracefully, by telling the user that their device's camera app is buggy) or use the camera APIs directly to take pictures.

Comment: Many thanks to your advices.I am actually using EXTRA_OUTPUT, just forget to type that line. And when u say "use the proper File constructor", do u mean that i should check the storage state, casue i have done that in my application oncreate. Or can u show me the proper code about the right way to specify the file path. Thanks!